# Javascript image slideshow using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

i'm trying to cycle through 3 images using a for loop in javascript. Here is my code:

```
<img name="slide" width="300" height="300">

var i=0;
var images = [];

images[0] = "images/1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/3.jpg";

function changeImage () {

    for(i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.slide.src = images[i]; 
    }
}


window.onload = changeImage;
```

Currently, only image 3 is displayed. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this is because your for loop run finishes instantly so there's no time for slides 1 and 2 to be shown.

Give this a try:

```
var currentImage = 0,
images = [
    "https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=100",
    "https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=101",
    "https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=102"
];

function initSlideshow() {  
    setImage(0);
    setInterval(function(){
        nextImage();
    },1000);
}

function nextImage() {
    if(images.length === currentImage + 1){
        currentImage = 0;
    } else {
        currentImage++;
    }
    setImage(currentImage);
}

function setImage(image) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.slide')[0].src = images[image];
}

window.onload = initSlideshow();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vvbdwazc/

Comment: Honestly man i'm a newb. How do i go about prolonging the loop to include the other two slides?

Comment: I'm writing a bit of code for you now, will update answer shortly :)

Comment: @rorymorris89 have a look at my answer.

Comment: Brixsta give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, only image 3 is displayed. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong
>   here?

it's all being displayed but the reason why you can only see the 3rd image is because you're not pausing for a certain time before displaying the next image hence it seems like it's not working.

use [**setInterval()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method to show each image after a specified time.

**Example:**

```
var i=0;
var images = [];

images[0] = "images/1.jpg";
images[1] = "images/2.jpg";
images[2] = "images/3.jpg";

function changeImage () {
    for(i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
        document.slide.src = images[i]; 
    }
}

var myVar = setInterval(function(){ changeImage() }, 1000);
```

You may later wish to prevent the [**setInterval()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method from executing any longer in that case have a look at [**clearInterval()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to work. pausing on a blank image briefly, and then goes to image 3 where it stays.

Comment: @Brixsta I know you've got the problem solved but see edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `for` works so fast it gets quickly to the third image. You could use instead some `setInterval` like this:

```
<img id="slide" width="300" height="300">
<script>
    var images = [];

    images[0] = "images/1.jpg";
    images[1] = "images/2.jpg";
    images[2] = "images/3.jpg";

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var slide = document.querySelector("#slide"); //Select the img element by ID
        slide.src = images[i++];
        if(i > images.length - 1)
            i = 0;
    }, 1000); //Time in milliseconds
</script>
```

This will change constantly back to the first image when it reaches the last one.

Edit: Forgot to mention. `setInterval` works like a "repeater", it will work indefinitely until you clear it. To clear it you need to asign it to a variable and then use `clearInterval` passing the variable.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){}, 1000) //example
clearInterval(interval);
```

Like so.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I gotta wrap my head around this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload = changeImage;` tells me you want to change the image on page load event?  In other words, the image changes only upon page load (or refresh).

Since state is not maintained by default (eg local storage or session storage or cookies) your best bet would be to use a random generator to choose randomly.  See [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)